# Increment a class name in Gutenberg block - Wordpress/Gutenberg + Timber + ACF

Tags: jquery, advanced-custom-fields, wordpress-gutenberg, timber

For a project I use Timber + ACF + Wordpress Gutenberg interface

I created a block with ACF intended for Gutenberg interface to display a flipbook.

To display multiple flipbook I need to link my Gutenberg block to a unique jQuery function.

To create a flipbook with the jQuery flipbook plugin, I wrote this code in **footer.twig** to be able to inject the url of my pdf :

```
$('.flipbook').flipBook({
    pdfUrl: "assets/pdf/link-to-unique-file.pdf"
});
```

For my Gutenberg block I wrote this code in **block-flipbook.twig** :

```
<article class="bloc">
     <div class="flipbook"></div>
</article>
```

But with Gutenberg the user can create multiple flipbook block

I would like to have something like that :

```
$('.flipbook-1').flipBook({
        pdfUrl: "assets/pdf/link-to-unique-file-1.pdf"
    });

$('.flipbook-2').flipBook({
        pdfUrl: "assets/pdf/link-to-unique-file-2.pdf"
    });
```

I would like something like that in my html file :

```
<article class="bloc">
      <div class="flipbook-1"></div>
</article>

<article class="bloc">
      <div class="flipbook-2"></div>
</article>
```

How to increment `flipbook` class in my Gutenberg block ?

Answer (score 1):

Getting the index for a block is probably the first thing you would think about, but you could also solve this a little differently.

I assume that you save the PDF file that should be displayed in one of your ACF fields. In that case, you could add the PDF src in a `data-pdf` attribute.

```
<article class="bloc">
     <div class="flipbook" data-pdf="{{ file.src }}"></div>
</article>
```

And then, you could write a jQuery function that looks for flipbooks and creates them.

```js
var flipbooks = $('.flipbook');

if (flipbooks.length > 0) {
  flipbooks.each(function(i, el) {
    var src = el.attr('data-pdf');

    el.flipBook({
      pdfUrl: src
    })
  });
}
```